# Arrange letters in one line

Tags: java

I have written a code that takes a string parameter and returns string that results from changing the capitalization of characters in the following way:

1. all vowels must be in uppercase(vowels are a,e,i,o,u)
2. all consonants must be in lowercase
3. any characters that are not letters must not be changed

Here is my code:

```
public class Simple {

    public char ChangeCase() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an input String: ");
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        //String isVowel = "aeiou";
        char c='\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
             c = inputString.charAt(i);
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'||c=='A'||c=='E'||c=='I'||c=='O'||c=='U') {
                c = Character.toLowerCase(c);

                System.out.println(c);
            }
            else if (c=='b'||c=='c'||c=='d'||c=='f'||c=='g'||c=='h'||c=='j'||c=='k'||c=='l'||c=='m'||c=='n'||c=='p'||c=='q'||c=='r'||c=='s'||c=='t'||c=='v'||c=='w'||c=='x'||c=='y'||c=='z'||
               c=='B'||c=='C'||c=='D'||c=='F'||c=='G'||c=='H'||c=='J'||c=='K'||c=='L'||c=='M'||c=='N'||c=='P'||c=='Q'||c=='R'||c=='S'||c=='T'||c=='V'||c=='W'||c=='X'||c=='Y'||c=='Z'){
                c = inputString.charAt(i);
                c =Character.toUpperCase(c);
                System.out.println(c);
            }
           else if(c=='@'||c=='!'||c=='"'||c==' '||c=='!'||c=='"'||c=='#'||c=='$'||c=='%'||c=='&'||c=='('|| c==')'||c=='*'||c=='+'||c==','||c=='-'||c=='.'||c=='/'||c==':'||c==';'||c=='<'||c=='='||c=='>'||c=='?'||c=='['||c==']'||c=='^'||c=='_'||c=='`'||c=='{'||c=='|'||c=='}'||c=='~'||c=='"'){
                c=inputString.charAt(i);
                c=c;
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            else
               c=c;

        }

        return c;

    }
}
```

Runner class:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simple smpl=new Simple();
        smpl.ChangeCase();

    }

}
```

Results i get when I type hello:

```
Enter an input String: hello
H
e
L
L
o
```

Expected results:

```
HeLLo
```

What should I change to get the expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `println` to `print` since `println` will always add an extra row.

Comment: `print` gives me this:
`HeLLo[INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"mojo":{"impl":"org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo","urls":["file:\/home\/brian\/.m2\/repository\/org\/codehaus\/mojo\/exec-maven-plugin\/1.2.1\/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar","file:\/home\/brian\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/reporting\/maven-reporting-api\/2.0.6\/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar","file:\/home\/brian\/.m2\/repository\/org\/apache\/maven\/doxia\/doxia-sink-api\/1.0-alpha-7\/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar","file:\/home\/brian\/.m2\/repository\/commons-cli\/commons-cli\/1.0\/commons-cli-1.0.jar"`

Comment: Add a `System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());` before your `return c;` statement

Comment: Thanks buddy, you nailed it.

Comment: @bademba good that it worked out. You can check this answer as the correct question if you're satisfied

Answer (score 3):

change `println()` to `print()` to omit the linefeed character from the output. Swap `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` to make the code do what the specification requires.

You are also currently not printing other characters such as linefeed (the requirement "any characters that are not letters must not be changed").
Get rid of the second `else if` and the `else` branches and replace them with

```
else {
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Also get rid of the extra `c = inputString.charAt(i);` statements. You only need the first one.

Regarding the problem you are solving, if I were you I would use regular expressions for that.

Anyway, here is a solution for Simple.java without regular expressions with some other improvements applied as well:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Simple {

    public void ChangeCase() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an input String: ");
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        for (char c: inputString.toCharArray()) {
            if (vowels.indexOf(c) != -1) { // found vowel
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // must be a consonant
                c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `print` gives me this: `HeLLo[INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"mojo":{"impl":"org.codehaus.mojo.exec.E‌​xecMojo","urls":["fi‌​le:\/home\/brian\/.m‌​2\/repository\/org\/‌​codehaus\/mojo\/exec‌​-maven-plugin\/1.2.1‌​\/exec-maven-plugin-‌​1.2.1.jar","file:\/h‌​ome\/brian\/.m2\/rep‌​ository\/org\/apache‌​\/maven\/reporting\/‌​maven-reporting-api\‌​/2.0.6\/maven-report‌​ing-api-2.0.6.jar","‌​file:\/home\/brian\/‌​.m2\/repository\/org‌​\/apache\/maven\/dox‌​ia\/doxia-sink-api\/‌​1.0-alpha-7\/doxia-s‌​ink-api-1.0-alpha-7.‌​jar","file:\/home\/b‌​rian\/.m2\/repositor‌​y

Answer (score 1):

As a first starter - simply swap

```
c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
```

respectively that other call that does `toUpperCase()` within your if blocks.

Your code is basically correct - you are just changing cases in the wrong place. So simply "swap" these calls! And of course - don't use `println()` - as this prints a "line" - meanning it adds a "new line" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just use print() method instead of println() because println() always add new line.

Comment: Using `print` gives me weird stuff that i dont need `HeLLo[INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"mojo":{"impl":"org.codehaus.mojo.exec.E‌​‌​xecMojo","urls":["‌​fi‌​le:\/home\/brian‌​\/.m‌​2\/repository\‌​/org\/‌​codehaus\/mo‌​jo\/exec‌​-maven-plu‌​gin\/1.2.1‌​\/exec-m‌​`

Answer (score 0):

First some hints for better code:

1. Structorize sour code, so please use Methods for each step (IF).
2. Only variable with 1 letter should be a iteration-variable, but better no variable with only 1 letter. (c)

Here some simple examples for you (can be optimized):

```
public class Simple {
    public void ChangeCase() {
        String resultString;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an input String: ");
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

        // make alle chars lower-case
        resultString = inputString.toLowerCase();

        // make vowels upper-case
        resultString = uppercaseVowels(resultString);

        // print the result or change to return String for main()
        System.out.println("Input: " + inputString);
        System.out.println("Result: " + resultString);
    }

    private String uppercaseVowels(String inputString) {
        inputString = inputString.replace('a', 'A');
        inputString = inputString.replace('e', 'E');
        inputString = inputString.replace('i', 'I');
        inputString = inputString.replace('o', 'O');
        inputString = inputString.replace('u', 'U');
        return inputString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only printing it at the end so it´s a little bit faster. But if you need it step-by-step you can change the uppercaseVowels()-Method to CHAR and call it for each char in stringBuilder(inputString.tolowercase());

Comment: will the code loop through to identify vowels and consonants to give a rest of the rules?

Comment: no, this code is just setting all so lowercase then uppercase all vowels. So constants are small und "untouched", vowels are uppercase and other chars are same like beforre because thei get ignored by upper-/lowercase.
This code is exactly printing and doing what you want, but with better structure and shorter without a needed iteration.